# AND operator not being evaluated in xsl file

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have an xsl that maps the value of an xml element depending on whether another value is true or false. I've never tried to use boolean operators in an xsl before, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

Here's an extract from my xsl with the part I'm having an issue with:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(payload/orderItem/processName, 'ResetPilotPassword') and /payload/orderItem/UsingOldSip = 'true'">
        <serviceId>
            <xsl:value select="/payload/orderItem/service/externalIds/externalId[displayName = 'MPLS ID']/externalId"/>
        </serviceId>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:when test="contains(payload/orderItem/processName, 'ResetPilotPassword') and /payload/orderItem/UsingOldSip = 'false'">
       <serviceId>
             <xsl:value-of select="payload/orderItem/bearerServiceIdentifier"/>
       </serviceId>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
        <serviceId>
            null
        </serviceId>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Essentially I have an order come in and then I'm evaluating the values of the elements "ProcessName" and "UsingOldSip" to determine what value to assign to the the element "serviceId". However the element is being populated with null instead of the correct value, and I've checked and those values are populated correctly in the order before they reach this xsl, so I must have something wrong with how I'm implementing the "and" operator here. Can someone see what the problem is? I've tried putting brackets around each condition, around the entire test, etc. and it's still not working.

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1:
Sample input xml as requested. The actual xml contains far more elements, but the key elements I need look like this:

```
 <orderItem xmlns="http://gatewayNamespace"> 
     <processName>orderResetPilotPassword</processName>        
     <orderId>12345</orderId>
     <accountId>56789</accountId>
     <emailAddress>test@gmail.com</emailAddress>
     <UsingOldSip>true</UsingOldSip>
 </orderItem>
```

Comment: Please, reformat your source code, so the horizontal scrollbar will disappear.

Comment: Could you also please show a sample of your input XML? Thank you!

Comment: i don't see any issue in and statement.May be there is something wrong with your xml tag path.Would you show your xml?

Comment: I've given a sample of the input xml. The full xml essentially looks like this, just with more elements. The xsl maps the rest of the elements correctly, this is the only part that isn't working for me.

Comment: `and /payload/orderItem/UsingOldSip = 'true'` doesn't do what you may think it does. It is true iff that element is *present*, not if it is *true*.

Comment: @EJP Wait, that's how it works? I thought writing it like`and /payload/orderItem/UsingOldSip` checks if the element is present, and then using the `=` checks the value of the element..? If that's not the case, then how do I check the value of the element ?

Comment: I suspect when you write `/a/b/c[X] and /a/b/c[Y]`, you are wanting to know if there is an instance of `/a/b/c` that satisfies both `X` and `Y`, whereas what this actually means is that there is an instance that satisfies `X` and another (maybe different) instance that satisfies `Y`. What you should have written is then `/a/b/c[X and Y]`.

Comment: This looks like a namespace problem, but without a [mcve] it's hard to tell. For example: your `orderItem` in the XML is in the namespace `xmlns="http://gatewayNamespace"`, but in your XPath expression it is selected without a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several `orderItem` elements, you should have something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="payload/orderItem">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(processName/text(), 'ResetPilotPassword') and UsingOldSip/text() = 'true'">
            <serviceId>
                <xsl:value select="service/externalIds/externalId[displayName = 'MPLS ID']/externalId/text()"/>
            </serviceId>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="contains(processName/text(), 'ResetPilotPassword') and UsingOldSip/text() = 'false'">
            <serviceId>
                <xsl:value-of select="bearerServiceIdentifier/text()"/>
            </serviceId>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <serviceId>
                null
            </serviceId>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if in another template element:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/payload/orderItem">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(processName/text(), 'ResetPilotPassword') and UsingOldSip/text() = 'true'">
            <serviceId>
                <xsl:value select="service/externalIds/externalId[displayName = 'MPLS ID']/externalId/text()"/>
            </serviceId>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="contains(processName/text(), 'ResetPilotPassword') and UsingOldSip/text() = 'false'">
            <serviceId>
                <xsl:value-of select="bearerServiceIdentifier/text()"/>
            </serviceId>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <serviceId>
                null
            </serviceId>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I only have the one orderItem element in the xml. It's the top most element, everything else is contained within it. I am curious about your use of "text()". What is the benefit of using this?

Comment: @Eon it gives you the text that's inside an element rather than the element itself